# How many different ways can be used to set-up his team

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

please if you can help me with it..
The coach from a football team ,will use 3 defenders players, 5 on center players and 2 attackers.If we suppose that the team have 20 players,that everyone it can be in every position,how many different ways the coach can plan his team?

What i did:

```
C1(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!r! so i have for C1 n=17 and r =3 C1= 17!/(17-3)!3!
C2(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!r! so i have for C2 n=12 and r =5 C1= 12!/(12-5)!5!
C3(n,r) = n!/(n-r)!r! so i have for C3 n=10 and r =2 C1= 10!/(10-2)!2!
```

Then i did this the result of C1,C2,C3 i add them like this

```
C1+c2 +C3
```

can you tell me where am i wrong?

Comment: You need to multiply, not add.  Also, I don't follow what you did for the combinations.  Why aren't there $\binom{20}{3}$ ways to choose the defenders?

Comment: i did wrong on that and on the multiply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the 20 people, first pick 3 of them to be defenders. There are $20 \choose 3$ such ways three people could be chosen. Now there are only 17 people left to pick from that could be a center player. So, there are $17 \choose 5$ ways to pick the next 5 players as centers. Now there are only 12 people left to pick from to be an attacker. So, there are $12 \choose 2$ ways to pick the next 2 players to be attackers.

You have to perform each of these three tasks - pick defenders, then pick centers, then pick attackers. So for each of the $20 \choose 3$ ways to finish the first task, there are *another* $17 \choose 5$ ways to complete the second task. And for each of the many ways to finish the first and second tasks, there are yet *another* $12 \choose 2$ ways to finish the third task.

The total is ${20 \choose 3} \times  {17 \choose 5} \times {12 \choose 2}$